# ¿Cómo enviar un array de objetos "dinámico" a una función que recibe arrays?

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms, object

Quiero enviar un `array` de objetos a una `función` de una `clase` externa, la cual recibirá el `array` de `objetos`, Ejemplo:

Esta es la `función` que recibe el `array` (supongamos que se encuentra en la `clase` `"Funciones"`):

```
public static void miFuncion(object[] objeto){
   //Código
}
```

Y lo mando llamar así para enviarle el `array` de `objetos`:

```
//Creo el array de tipo object, en el cual almaceno TextBox
object[] textBox = new object[]{ txt1, txt2, txt3 };

Funciones.miFuncion(textBox);
```

Funciona correctamente, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de enviar dicho `array` sin la necesidad de crearlo para posteriormente enviarlo. No sé, algo similar a esto:

> Funciones.miFuncion([txt1, txt2, txt3]);

Y que lo reconozca como `array` de tipo `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

es tan simple como

```
Funciones.miFuncion(new object[]{ txt1, txt2, txt3 });
```

Comment: aunque no me guste crear objetos anónimos esta es la respuesta correcta.